# Tello Drone Video Streaming Latency (Python)

Tags: python, video-streaming, latency, drone.io

I am currently stuck with high video streaming latency on python with OpenCV. I have the video streaming set up but the latency (about 800ms) is hard to deal with when manually controlling the drone with pygame. I know that it isn't the drone because when I use the Tello app, the latency is unnoticeable. Does anyone have any experience with video streaming with the Tello drone?

Answer (score -2):

I used the following code in Windows 10 and could display the video stream from the drone without a delay. However, note that this uses the tellopy library.

```
   def video_thread():
        global drone
        global run_video_thread
        global av
        print('START Video thread')
        drone.start_video()
        try:                                                                                                                            
            container = av.open(drone.get_video_stream())
            frame_count = 0
            while True:
                for frame in container.decode(video=0):
                    frame_count = frame_count + 1
                    image = cv2.cvtColor(numpy.array(frame.to_image()), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
                    cv2.imshow('Original', image)
                    cv2.waitKey(1)
            cv2.destroyWindow('Original')
        except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
            print('KEYBOARD INTERRUPT Video thread ' + e)
        except Exception as e:
            exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
            print('EXCEPTION Video thread ' + e)
    
    def main():    
        global drone
        drone = tellopy.Tello()
        drone.connect()
        
        try:
            threading.Thread(target=video_thread).start()
    
        except e:
            print(str(e))
        finally:
            print('Shutting down connection to drone...')        
            drone.quit()
            exit(1)
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```